# asp.net vb how to make hidden additional attachment hidden and visible?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, attachment

Hi I tried in afew manners but wasnt able to make it work.
I want to make 5 attachment options in that 4 out of the 5 are hidden.
but when he clicks "more attachment" link it will show the other 4.

any ideas?

Im using ASP.NET with VB

plus if you need my code let me know!

thank you!

Comment: it is better if you showed your code and stated what actually you tried.

Comment: most of the things I tried are out of lack of knowledge so I dont really have much to show for my efforts..

Comment: Have you tried using a MultiView panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with many ways, one of them is enclose your 4 attachments within a `div` styled with `display:none` and by using `javascript` shows them in `onclick` events of `more attachment` link, something like this

```
 <div style="display:none" id="moreattchdiv">
   <!-- 1st attachment -->
   <!-- 2nd attachment -->
   <!-- 3rd attachment -->
   <!-- 4th attachment -->
 </div>
 <div onclick="showmore()">more attachments</div>
 <script>
   function showmore()
   {
       var moreattachdiv = $('#moreattchdiv');
       if(moreattachdiv.is(':visible'))
       {
          moreattachdiv.hide();
       }
       else
       {
          moreattachdiv.show();
       }
   }
 </script>
```

**Note** I am using [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) in my script

you can test that example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w2s7M/2/)

**Update**
insert this line into header tag of your page.If you are using master page insert it into its header tag

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you would like to do it without jquery replace the `showmore()` function with this code

```
  function showmore()
   {
      var moreattachdiv = document.getElementById('moreattchdiv')
      if(moreattachdiv.style.display=='none')
      {
         moreattachdiv.style.display=''
      }
      else
      {
        moreattachdiv.style.display='none'
      }
   }
```

you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w2s7M/3/)

Comment: opps, sorry I forget, you should add the reference to jquery library, I updated my answer

Comment: thank you! it worked, but can you please tell me how can I also hide them again when I press the  "more attachment" link?

Comment: I updated my code to show/hide the attachment div and the links to test it

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the hidden 4 attachments in a div that has the style set to `display: none`, then when you click the more attachments link, it would set the style of that hidden div to `display: block`.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmmzH/

Comment: It's basically the same thing Amir posted, just with pure Javascript instead of jquery.